# Does light have its own mass?

Tags: visible-light, photons, mass, relativity, mass-energy

If light has mass, then why don't we have light particles accumulated all over the earth?

Comment: Suppose you leave a heavy lead weight and a lot of ping-pong balls alone in a room. Why doesn't the gravity of the lead weight attract all the ping-pong balls, so that they cluster around the lead weight?

Comment: Because that's not how gravity works, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photons have momentum, but no rest mass.

Comment: So does the mass vary?

Comment: No, it's always 0. Momentum does vary depending on wavelength.

Comment: So how does it exist if it's 0?

Comment: Mass is not a necessary requirement for something to 'exist'. Photons have both energy and momentum, but no rest mass.

Comment: This is true only for a single free photon or for photons flying in the same direction. Any system of two or more photons at an angle to each other has a rest mass. Also photons confined inside a mirror box also have a rest mass.